# Jekyll PDF URL *not* ending in ".pdf"

Tags: jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I have a Jekyll blog hosted on GitHub Pages.  On the blog is my resume (resume.pdf).  The url to access this is something like "http://example.com/resume.pdf"  .  Is there any way I can get rid of the file extension, ie. have the URL be "http://example.com/resume" ?  I have scoured the Jekyll help pages to no avail.

Comment: You can iframe the pdf on a page called resume.md. You can also force a download on this url. Jekyll allows you to rewrite the .html part.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

To change this url, you would need to add some rules in the .htaccess (which you can't in github pages)

Even if you could, removing the extension would not allow the server to give a content type. This means your browser would not know what to do with this url.

Why don't you create a page resume that is going to include the link to your pdf or even a html redirect to the pdf ?